# How to ensure that data is inserted only one time in sqlite

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I'm using a `web service` which returns data in `JSON` format like this:

```
{"content":[{"id":"1","asset_id":"62","title":"sample page","alias":"","introtext":"","fulltext":"Some Contents"},{"id":"2","asset_id":"62","title":"sample page2","alias":"","introtext":"","fulltext":"Some Contents"},{"id":"3","asset_id":"62","title":"sample page3","alias":"","introtext":"","fulltext":"Some Contents"}]}
```

`onCreate()` of `MainActivity.java` is :

```
boolean myFlag = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myView);

    setFlag = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);

    dataSource = new ContentsDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();
    parseAndIsertData();

}
```

the `parseAndInsertData()` is :

`EDIT`

```
private void parseAndIsertData() {
    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    MyJSONParser jParser = new MyJSONParser();

    contentDataObject = new ContentDataObject();        
    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(BASE_URL); 

    try {
        // first time check if data is inserted
        editor = setFlag.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(MY_KEY, true);            

        // Getting Array of Contents
        jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(MOBILE_CONTENT);          
        // looping through All Contents

        if(!myFlag){            

            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                contentDataObject.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt(MOBILE_CONTENT_ID));
                contentDataObject.setTitle(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(MOBILE_CONTENT_TITLE));
                contentDataObject.setFulltext(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(MOBILE_CONTENT_FULLTEXT));
                contentDataObject.setState(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt(MOBILE_CONTENT_STATE));
                contentDataObject.setNewValue(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt(MOBILE_CONTENT_NEW));
                contentDataObject.setHeader(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(MOBILE_CONTENT_HEADER));
                contentDataObject.setColor(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt(MOBILE_CONTENT_COLOR));
                contentDataObject.setNext(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(MOBILE_CONTENT_NEXT));
                contentDataObject.setPrevious(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(MOBILE_CONTENT_PREVIOUS));

                contentDataObject = dataSource.create(contentDataObject);

                Log.i(MY_TAGT, "Data Inserted " + contentDataObject.getId() + " Times");

            }

            myFlag = setFlag.getBoolean(MY_KEY, false);

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Now My `logcat` for first time launch is :

[image]

and when I relaunch the app my `logcat` is :

[image]

Now I want ask that is this approach correct or not if `YES`! then will I be able to update that later on!! 
Thanks!

Comment: create ur table with [UNIQUE constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint) to avoid duplicate insertion for columns

Comment: after inserting data in db store some flag in `SharedPreferences` like if successfully inserted then store true otherwise false and in oncreate of Activity before requesting data from server check SharedPreferences flag value if true means no need to request it again or if false then make an request to server

Comment: I have tried many times but I can not get result if you can give me some example please!!

Comment: for what u want example plz edit your question with the latest code then i will try to help u.

Comment: ok I'm showing you latest code and see If it is correct or not, because I want that the data should not be insert again and again but it may be updated in future!!

Comment: Dear! now see my code! and please make changes if you see I have mistaken!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25613/discussion-between-arshad-ali-arshay-and--k)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this code will insert the data multiple times.  It will be up to you to implement a pattern that allows only one row.

You need to either query the data source first and not insert the data if it exists or you need to delete the data from the data source and then insert it every time.  There are other patterns but these two will be the most common.  Which one you choose will depend on what the data is and how you want it maintained or updated.

Comment: First thanks for your answer, Now I want to ask that is it good practice that we delete and insert data again and again? will this not affect the performance of App??

Comment: It depends on your data.  If this is one row of infrequently updated static data then delete/insert guarantees the most correctness.  If this is a large number of rows of changing data then delete/insert would be a bad choice.  In that case your data should have a primary key and you use that to determine existence and handle updates.

I would advise against an approach that writes data to one datastore  (like SQLite) and then uses something in another datastore (like preferences) to determine if the first store was written.  That can lead to real mismatches if anything gets complicated.

Answer (score 0):

1. define a column in your table to be `primary key` or `unique`
2. use `SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(...)` with the `conflictAlgorithm` parameter (the last one) set to ``SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE`

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int%29)